# Raycast hits an object only from right side

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I Wanted to do a raycast from players position to my capsules position that has only capsule collider but for some reason it only hits from the left side

```
 RaycastHit2D _ray = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, collision.transform.position, 100f, playerL);
```

[image: picture of the problem]

layers are all correct because the left side works fine so I dont know what to do

Comment: I always thought that second parameter was a direction :P nothing in the docs says position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I see is that you put position as second parameter of Raycast while it should be direction. You need Linecast there or calculate direction properly. Second if you start your raycast inside the collider that collider will not be hit (but you probably know that, just solve the first problem and it should be running)